# registration process with contact from 7?

Tags: user-registration, plugin-contact-form-7

It is possible to create registration process with contact from 7.

i want all the features of contact from 7 in my registration from.

my registration from is in popup on my site.

if possible with contact from 7 then tell me how or give me some other idea for registration process.

Thanks

Comment: Nice question but i dont think so it is working with contact form 7. you have to use custom jquery code for this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the plugin contact form 7 to Database Extension and then follow the directions at this post:

http://geektastical.com/2011/05/how-to-create-a-pop-up-wordpress-email-contact-form/

Comment: This does not answer the question *at all*!